# Collection_select form_for saying it's blank, when it's not

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, form-for, html-select

I have a Company Model and a User Model. A User belongs_to a Company a Company has many users. A company is created and then people can sign up individually and that will create the association. I'm trying to have a select box so when a user is signing up they pick their company from a select box, which is populated using the pluck method for the Company model.

When a user signs up it's saying that the select box is empty...even though it appears not to be. What am I doing wrong?

Company Model

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :company_admin, :company_name, :employee_number, :street_address, :city, :state_abbreviation, :zip_code
has_many :users

validates :company_admin, presence: true
validates :company_name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
validates :employee_number, presence: true
validates :street_address, presence: true
validates :city, presence: true
validates :state_abbreviation, presence: true
validates :zip_code, presence: true



end
```

Users Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :company, :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :image,   :team_id
belongs_to :company
end
```

Companies Controller

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
    @company = Company.find(params[:id])
  end


  def new
    @company = Company.new
  end

  def create
    @company = Company.new(params[:company])
    if @company.save  
      redirect_to signup_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
 end

 def update
   if @company.update_attributes(params[:company])
     flash[:success] = "Company Information Updated"
    sign_in @company
    redirect_to @company
  else
  render 'edit'
  end
end

end
```

New User View

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :company, :class => 'col-left' %>
   <%= collection_select(:company_id, :company_id, Company.all, :id, :company_name,  {:include_blank => true}) %>
   <%= f.label :email, :class => 'col-left' %>
   <%= f.text_field :email, :class => 'col-right' %>
   <%= f.label :name, :class => 'col-left' %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
   <%= f.label :password, :class => 'col-left' %>
   <%= f.password_field :password %>
   <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password", :class => 'col-left' %>
   <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
   <%= image_submit_tag "/assets/create-account.png" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add f. to the collection select so it was

```
f.collection_select(:company_id, Company.all, :id, :company_name, {:include_blank => true})
```